# Enabling STS for quarkus-loggin-cloudwatch extension

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, quarkus, quarkus-native

The quarkus-logging-cloudwatch requires quarkus-log-cloudwatch-access-key-id and quarkus-log-cloudwatch-access-key-secret in application.properties. Is there any way to leverage this extension without specifying the access-key and secret, but through STS, just like we can use other extensions for ssm, secrets manager etc?

Added the following in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkiverse.logging.cloudwatch</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-logging-cloudwatch</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Added the following in application.properties:

```
quarkus.log.amazon-cloudwatch.enabled=true
quarkus.log.cloudwatch.region=us-east-1
quarkus.log.cloudwatch.log-group=quarkus-cw-log-group
quarkus.log.cloudwatch.log-stream-name=quarkus-cw-log-stream
```

I do not want to add the following in the application.properties, but want to use this cloudwatch extension using sts:

```
quarkus-log-cloudwatch-access-key-id= 
quarkus-log-cloudwatch-access-key-secret=
```

Is there any way to achieve the same while using org.jboss.logging.Logger? I understand, this works if I pass the access-key-id and access-key-secret, but in production I cannot pass these, and will have to rely on STS.